# Customuser model doesn't return username

Tags: python, django

I have a customuser model with

```
class customuser(AbstractUser):
    # additional fields    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I have another model, that becomes the foreign key for this model

```
class bfs_support_ticket_model(models.Model):
    ticket_created_by = models.ForeignKey(customuser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Why doesn't Django renders username for the form, but render or returns username everywhere correctly

```
class ticket_edit_form(ticket_create_form):

    # ticket_created_by = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'readonly' : True})) # does not work in this way

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ticket_edit_form,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.fields['ticket_created_by'].disabled = True
        self.fields['ticket_created_by'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'readonly' : True}) # doesnot work in this way too

    class Meta:
        model=bfs_support_ticket_model
        exclude=['ticket_last_updated_by']
```

When the form is rendered it just prints the `customuser.id` instead of `customuser.username`

But when no form initialization is made, it return the `customuser.username` correctly

i.e. when

```
class ticket_edit_form(ticket_create_form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ticket_edit_form,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ticket_created_by'].disabled = True # only this line present it renders customuser.username


    class Meta:
        model=bfs_support_ticket_model
        exclude=['ticket_last_updated_by']
```

Please help me, where I am going wrong

Edit:
Why does

```
self.fields['ticket_created_by'].disabled = True # prints username
```

while

```
self.fields['ticket_created_by'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'readonly' : True}) # this doesn't
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observations:

Since the field is a Foreignkey, it gets rendered as a `modelchoicefield`, hence initializing the field as charfield, only prints the exact value present in the db (in this case `customuser.id`)

To make it render properly, I had to initialize it as a `modelchoicefield`, like

```
ticket_created_by = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = customuser.objects.all(), widget = forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'custom-select custom-select-sm mb-3', 'disabled' : True}))
```

Please advice, if this is a correct solution

Answer (score 0):

```
class bfs_support_ticket_model(models.Model):
    ticket_created_by = models.ForeignKey(customuser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.ticket_created_by.customuser.username
```

Comment: Still no luck, it return only the id